# Mapping a string (key) to an XML schema (value)

Tags: java

I am trying to map a String (key) to an XML schema with few variable that will change (marked with $ sign).

I am not sure what is the best way to do this in terms of the map to use (hashmap?) and the type to use for the xml schema (map a string to ..?)

Also, I am not entirely sure if passing the strings that will change (let's say: id and name for example) as part of the key and replace them or get the schema back and replace the variable once I process the schema again.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am not really generating a new schema, I simply have an already generated schema (template) with couple of things need to be replaced. I just need to return that schema once requested by a key (different schemas for different keys). I am not sure JAXB is for that, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of implementing this on your own, [bind](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnazf.html.) the schema types to Java classes or use some sort of templating engine like [StringTemplate](http://stringtemplate.org/).

Comment: I am not really generating a new schema, I simply have an already generated schema (template) with couple of things need to be replaced. I just need to return that schema once requested by a key (different schemas for different keys). I am not sure JAXB is for that, is it?

Answer (score 0):

So is it not simplest to treat the Schema as a string, and just hold it in a Map.  Then when you pull it out, do a replace/replaceAll on the schema, and return it.  I think that covers what you want?